# Optimizing an insert/update loop in a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have two tables `wholesaler_catalog` and `wholesaler_catalog_prices`. The latter has a foreign key reference to the former.

`wholesaler_catalog_prices` has a column called `cost_type` which can be either `RETAIL` or `DISCOUNT`.

Consider row Foo in `wholesaler_catalog`. Foo has two entries in `wholesaler_catalog_prices` - one for `RETAIL` and one for `DISCOUNT`. I want to split up Foo into Foo1 and Foo2, such that Foo1 points to RETAIL and Foo2 points to DISCOUNT. (The reasons for doing this are complex which I won't go into - it's part of a larger migration)

I have made a stored procedure that looks like this:

```sql
do
$$
declare
    f record;
    new_id int;
begin
    for f in select catalog_id from 
        (select catalog_id, cost_type, row_number() over (partition by catalog_id) from wholesaler_catalog_prices
        group by catalog_id, cost_type
        order by catalog_id) as x
        where row_number > 1
    loop 
        insert into wholesaler_catalog 
        (item_number, name, catalog_log_id)
        select item_number, name, catalog_log_id from wholesaler_catalog
        where id = f.catalog_id
        returning id into new_id;
        -- RAISE NOTICE '% copied to %', f.catalog_id, new_id;
        update wholesaler_catalog_prices set catalog_id = new_id where catalog_id = f.catalog_id and cost_type = 'RETAIL';
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

The problem is that there are about 100k such records and it takes a very long time to run (I cancelled the run after 30 minutes). Is there anyway I can optimize the procedure to run faster?

Comment: Hi, it's hard to know what's making your code block slow without a data sample and without knowing how the columns are indexed. Could you add the create table statements with a few sample data? preferably within a fiddle ;)

Comment: We ended up taking an approach where we exported data as a csv and re-imported it in the application.